# Job timeout and excessive attempt issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I'm working with a job with a timeout set to 21600 seconds. However, when the execution time exceeds this limit, I encounter an error message stating:

> App\Jobs\JobName has been attempted too many times or run too long.
> The job may have previously timed out.

I've taken the initiative to resolve this issue by increasing the timeout from 4 hours to 6 hours, but the problem persists. Could you provide some guidance on how to address this issue? I'm particularly interested in understanding why the job might still be timing out despite the increased limit and what steps I can take to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

What does that job do? Can you pls share the source code of that job? I will update my answer accordingly.

It's not a good idea to attempt a job too many times. Pls specify a [tries](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#max-attempts) property to get a clearer error message.

Comment: I have a maximum of 3 tries.